# What is the size of a recaptcha token generated from the recaptcha widget?

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

Trying to send the recaptcha token to a backend service for verification and I need to know the size of the token. Is it a standard size in bytes or is it variable

Answer (score 2):

The generated reCAPTCHA token is not a fixed size in either bytes or number of characters. The length is variable so I would not try to assign it to a fixed size string or buffer.

Comment: I'm trying to send it as a header down to a backend service. Just concerned about reaching the server header limit.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you do not pass the token in a header, we have seen many instances of the token exceeding the header length limit.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, reCAPTCHA token char are keep on increasing, since we have char limit validation in body payload, its failing. Currently we set it as 3000 but the token is exceeding that. Any idea what is the max char length of reCAPTCHA token (Enterprise).